# Compose textview focus issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a form in my application for set password. it has two outlined textfield and I wanted the first field always to be focused when screen composes. but unfortunately it always focus the last textfield.

IS there any way to make sure that the first compose is always focused.

```
   Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    PasswordInputField(
                        content = stringResource(id = R.string.new_password),
                        textState = formPasswordState,
                        focusRequester = focusRequester,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                        initialFocus = true,
                        onFocusChanged = {
                            viewModel.validatePasswordScreen(formPasswordState.value)
                            showSheet = false
                        }, focusManager = focusManager, onValueChanged = { showSheet = it }
                    )
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }

                    PasswordInputField(
                        content = stringResource(id = R.string.confirm_password),
                        textState = formConfirmPasswordState,
                        focusRequester = focusRequester,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
                        initialFocus = false,
                        onFocusChanged = {
                            viewModel.validateConfirmPassword(formPasswordState.value)
                            showSheet = false
                        }, focusManager = focusManager, onValueChanged = { showSheet = it }
                    )
                }
```

common composable for password is

```
OutlinedTextField(
   *****
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 10.dp)
        .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
            textState.onFocusChange(focusState.isFocused)
            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                onValueChanged(false)
            }
        }
        .focusRequester(focusRequester),
   
   
  
)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to apply `focusRequester` for 2nd input field. Just make `focusRequester` nullable and apply it only if its not null.

```
@Composable
fun PasswordInputField(
...
focusRequester: FocusRequester? = null,
...
){

    OutlinedTextField(
       ...,
       modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 10.dp)
        .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
            textState.onFocusChange(focusState.isFocused)
            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                onValueChanged(false)
            }
        }
        .conditional(focusRequester != null){
            focusRequester(focusRequester!!)
         },
         ...
    )

}
```

```
fun Modifier.conditional(
    condition: Boolean,
    orElse: (@Composable Modifier.() -> Modifier)? = null,
    modifier: @Composable Modifier.() -> Modifier
): Modifier = composed {
    if (condition) {
        modifier.invoke(this)
    } else {
        if (orElse != null) {
            orElse.invoke(this)
        } else {
            this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is you are using same focusRequestor for both of the password fields, you should assign different ones.